# parsing error in jpa query getting parsing error

Tags: jpa

```
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
query.append("SELECT e FROM DBMGPersonMetaData e WHERE
    e.moduleUniqueId.extension= ?1 AND e.ConsType ");

query.append("IN ( SELECT  CASE WHEN " +"INSTR(p.description, ' ') = 0  "+
"   THEN SUBSTR(p.description,1)   "+ " WHEN INSTR(p.description, ' ') !=0 "+
"   THEN SUBSTR(p.description,1,INSTR(p.description, ' ')-1)  END"+ " AS ee  FROM DBProjectMetaData p WHERE p.projectUniqueId.extension= ?2");
dbModuleperson = (DBMGPersonMetaData) 
entityManager.createQuery(query.toString()).setParameter(1,"12").
setParameter(2,"12").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Would you mind to post the exception you're getting?

Comment: Just a guess - in some SQL Dialects `CASE` expression must end with `ELSE` clause. What DB are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle Db. dont remeber the exact exception but it was something like "encounterd e.ConsType IN ( SELECT but expecting "(" ,"*" "..

Comment: Not sure if this one is valid: `SELECT e FROM DBMGPersonMetaData e`. Try `SELECT e.* FROM DBMGPersonMetaData e` instead.

Comment: Also, try to make it work in some SQL IDE, such as `Oracle SQL Developer`, before running it in `JPA`. This should not be related to `JPA`.

Comment: same jpa query i ran in sql developer.It was running fine there.but in jpa it was throwing exception

Comment: Try everything that I advised, and post the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the `native SQL query` in `JPA`, you should use this method instead:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(query.toString());
```

The method you're using (`createQuery`) accepts either `JPQL` query or the `CriteriaQuery`.

Comment: i tried with the native query.It is working fine now.I guess INSTR is not a JPQL key word that's why it was throwing the  parsing exception.

Comment: @sandeep Definitely. You may accept the answer if it worked for you.